# Accessing Workgroup Shared Folder from Domain

Tags: windows-xp, networking, lan, administrator, domain

I have a **domain** and a **workgroup**. My users are supposed to **upload files on regular basis to several shared folders on the workgroup.**

I have difficulty accessing the workgroup shared folders without firstly mapping them to a drive letter. I do not need (neither want) to create separate network drives for say 15 different workgroup folders (they are on separate PCS).

Is there a way how to **create a shortcut to shared workgroup folder** so that the **destination workgroup folder will open on clicking it?**

*Here are the key remarks:*

- The OS used: Windows XP SP3
- The 15 shared workgroup folders are on different PCs
- Ideally, I wish to access them without username and password, if possible
- If the workgroup shared folders can not be accessed without username and password, I will create identcal user and very simple password for all of them, but i wish to have them used without asking users to enter it
- I wish to accomplish this on clicking one file (shortcut to the shared folder or .bat script)
- After the user clicks the file, I wish to have open the desired location
- The solution can be achieved with simple script
- I do not wish to use: USE NET and map separate drive for every location

Thank you.

Comment: Can you access the desired shares with `\\<computer's name>` or `\\<computer's IP address>`?

Comment: @techie007, hi and thanks for your response. Well I can ping the host name and get translated IP address. then I can use the following: **"USE NET \\hostname\SharedFolder /USER:MyUser MyPasssword."** This works. However, my point was creating just shortcut, so the users cna click and access the target folder, whitout the need to map the destination folder through USE NET.

Comment: Why not just make a standard shortcut pointing to `\\hostname\SharedFolder`?

Comment: @techie007:of course I tried it as the first option. Basically, what you propose is what I am looking for. However, if I do try to access the folder directly in Windows Explorer, after cca 1 minute I get a response from the PC: **"the directory cannot be found"**. After couple of hours searching I came here to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Notepad and type the below statements in a file and save it as batch script(.bat).
Replace all passwords and usernames for individual shares as needed ( Yes password comes before username :) )

```
NET USE "\\<computername1>\<sharename1>" <password> /u:<username>  
NET USE "\\<computername2>\<sharename2>" <password> /u:<username>  
..
NET USE "\\<computernameN>\<sharenameN>" <password> /u:<username>
```

Then try accessing the shares with the shortcuts created.
If you face any errors regarding Multiple Sessions run "NET USE * /DELETE" before executing the batch file.
The shortcuts should work now. Sometimes the actual folders might not be visible if the ABE(Access Based Enumeration) is enabled and read permissions for that share are denied though this might not be the reason in your case .

Comment: Can you please let me know if this worked out well ? I'm a newbie and the green "tick" isn't as reaffirming as a statement :)